# How can I add a section/subsection to the TOC but not the navigation bar?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm making a presentation using Beamer, and I would like for my subsection titles to appear in the table of contents, but *not* the navigation bar.  I only know that

```
\subsection*{title}
```

does the opposite.  Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: By "appear in the navigation bar" what do you mean? What outer style are you using? (I'm not sure whether this will be relevant to the solution, but it might be...)

Comment: @Seamus I am using a custom style that is based on PaloAlto.  The navigation bar in this theme is located in the left side bar.  I wish for the navigation bar to include sections, but not subsections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is pass this option to your theme:

```
\usetheme[hideallsubsections]{PaloAlto}
```

If you're using a custom theme, try:

```
\usetheme[hideallsubsections]{CustomTheme}
```

It *might* work...

Internally, `PaloAlto` uses `sidebar` as the basic outertheme. ( To solve this question I looked up `sidebar` (I found the path LaTeX was using in the log file) and saw that it declared the `hideallsubsections` option. Incidentally, it also declares a `hideothersubsections` option... There's also a `right` option, which puts the sidebar on the right. It looks weird...

In fact, you can recreate most of `PaloAlto` out of basic themes like so:

```
\useoutertheme{sidebar}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}
```

This is exactly how the beamer theme does it!

Comment: What if \usetheme{Frankfurt} and I want to do the same but with section only (not with subsections).