# Add a section to beamer table of contents but not to navigation bar

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, mini-frames

This question has been asked before, but [for a different beamer theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15239/how-can-i-add-a-section-subsection-to-the-toc-but-not-the-navigation-bar). The answer there did not make it clear to me how to deal with my case, illustrated in this example (which I think is close to minimal):

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
    \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=white}
    \useoutertheme{miniframes}  
    % ^ dots up top
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    % ^ disable annoying footer
\newcommand{\mytoc}{
    \tableofcontents[ 
        currentsubsection, 
        hideothersubsections, 
        subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,
        ]} 
    \newcommand{\mytocslide}{
    \begin{frame}
        \mytoc
    \end{frame}}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{hiya}
    yo
\end{frame}
\mytocslide
\section{Second section}\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
    yoyo
\end{frame}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section not in top nav}
\begin{frame}
    yoyoyo
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The resulting document includes the extra section in the TOC but not the nav bar (as desired), but it looks weird in the TOC.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131647/difference-between-section-and-section-in-beamer

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131647/difference-between-section-and-section-in-beamer) and the answer. `\section` inserts a new entry into the table of contents at the appropriate tree-level and also inserts a new entry into the navigation bars. But `\section*` only adds an entry in the navigation bars, not in the table of contents.

Comment: When you say it 'looks weird', could you elaborate? What should it look like? It looks fine to me although it is not a link as the other entries are. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @cfr Sorry, I didn't think to actually include a picture. You are correct, I meant that I expected it to show up blue (like a link) and similarly spaced to the other entries.

Comment: @MMA Thanks, I knew that question was related (see my comment above yours :) ), but it does not solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To achieve the same formatting as a regular section entry, you need some additional work: section entries in the ToC have a vertical extra spacing of `1.5em` and they have a special color, so you need to say something like:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip1.5em}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure} text}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
    \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=white}
    \useoutertheme{miniframes}  
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\newcommand{\mytoc}{
    \tableofcontents[ 
        currentsubsection, 
        hideothersubsections, 
        subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,
        ]} 
\newcommand{\mytocslide}{
    \begin{frame}
        \mytoc
    \end{frame}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{hiya}
    yo
\end{frame}
\mytocslide

\section{Second section}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
    yoyo
\end{frame}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip1.5em}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure} Section in ToC but not in the navigation bar}

\begin{frame}
    yoyoyo
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC, showing the new additional entry, not present in the navigation bar:

[image]

A more robust solution (that doesn't require manual intervention and that will even give you an hyperlink) can be achieved by defining a new command using the exact way in which sections are included in the ToC (the relevant definition can be found in the file `beamerbasesection.sty`):

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
    \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=white}
    \useoutertheme{miniframes}  
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\newcommand{\mytoc}{
    \tableofcontents[ 
        currentsubsection, 
        hideothersubsections, 
        subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,
        ]} 
\newcommand{\mytocslide}{
    \begin{frame}
        \mytoc
    \end{frame}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addsectiontotoc[1]{%
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\beamer@sectionintoc{\the\c@section}{#1}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}%
    {\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{hiya}
    yo
\end{frame}
\mytocslide

\section{Second section}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
    yoyo
\end{frame}

\addsectiontotoc{Section in ToC but not in the navigation bar}

\begin{frame}
    yoyoyo
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that I could customize the appearance of the TOC line. It looks like I can do both steps in one: `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\vskip1.5em\protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure} Conclusion}`

Comment: @Frank You're welcome! By the way, I added a new, more robust solution to my answer; this new possibility might be of interest for you.